# Можно ли использовать volatile переменную для арифметических операций?

Tags: java, многопоточность, volatile

Допустим, есть несколько потоков, они прибавляют некоторые значения в `volatile`-переменную (типа синглтон), и выводят значения этой переменной после суммирования в реальном времени (ну должно быть в реальном времени). Все операции - только с целыми числами.

Можно ли так делать? Какие возникнут проблемы?

Comment: Хм.. Был уверен, что нет, но эксперимент подтверждаться не хочет: http://ideone.com/D3oNWv

Comment: @Qwertiy там может быть задействован один процессор, с которым такое поведение будет довольно ожидаемым (но не гарантированным); возможно, там происходят дополнительные оптимизации, сводящие все к какому-нибудь CAS. Более того, при изменении инкремента на x + 1 / y + 1 у меня и без волатайла стали отдаваться корректные значения.

Comment: @etki, честно говоря, у меня при замене `" "` на `"\n"` в выводе начинали получаться корректные значения в обоих случаях. Да и так отклонение довольно маленькое. Уж не знаю, что они там намутили.

Comment: @Qwertiy `-XX:+UnlockDIagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly`  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Qwertiy а вот и корректный тест подъехал http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jcstress/file/3082ed6f0092/jcstress-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/samples/ConcurrencySample_01_OperationAtomicity.java (из http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jcstress/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так делать нельзя. Операции с `volatile`-переменной не являются атомарными. Ключевое слово `volatile` лишь сообщает компилятору о том, что переменная может быть изменена либо извне программы, либо другим потоком и нельзя кэшировать её значение, т.е. значение всегда должно считываться/записываться напрямую в ячейку памяти.

В качестве примера рассмотрим выполнение кода

```
i = i + 1;
```

Пусть `i == 0` и у нас есть два потока, одновременно выполняющих этот код. Тогда возможна следующая ситуация (`regX` - регистр процессора):

```
   Поток 1          Поток 2         Результат

mov regA, [i]  |                 |  regA == 0
               |  mov regB, [i]  |  regB == 0
               |  add regB, 1    |  regB == 1
               |  mov [i], regB  |  i    == 1
add regA, 1    |                 |  regA == 1
mov [i], regA  |                 |  i    == 1
```

То есть, код выполнился два раза, но переменная `i` тем не менее увеличилась только на единицу.

Если Вам нужен потокобезопасный счётчик, используйте [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Answer (score 3):

Если переменной только присваивается или читается значение, то никаких проблем не будет. Но если переменная используется как аккумулятор, то возможны сюрпризы. Так код

```
vlt = vlt + 10
```

преобразовывается в такой

```
int x = vlt;
x = x + 10;
vlt = x;
```

Соответственно на момент присваивания

```
vlt = x;
```

в поле может лежать любое значение